# Check if url contains blacklisted strings javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, include, indexof

If i have an array of blacklisted words like so:

```
banLinks = ["hello.com","test.net","this.com"];
```

and I'd like to check if `myLink` I got through `a.getAttribute("href")` contains one of those words what'd be the best way to go? Right now i'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
            for (let i = 0; i < banLinks.length; ++i) {
                if ( myLink.indexOf(banLinks[i]) <= -1 ){
                    urllink = myLink;
                }
            }
```

full section:

```
    var urllink;
    const banLinks = ["hello.com","test.net","this.com"];
    for (let j = 0; j < titlesArray.length; ++j) {
        if ( "some logic not important" ){

            for (let i = 0; i < banLinks.length; ++i) {
                if ( titlesArray[j].link.indexOf(banLinks[i]) <= -1 ){
                    urllink = titlesArray[j].link;
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in a situation where you're unable to use `Array.prototype.findIndex`? (I.e. you must support IE)

If not:

```js
const banLinks = ["hello.com","test.net","this.com"];
const is_banned = banLinks.findIndex(bl => myLink.indexOf(bl) > -1) > -1
```

And with your edited example:

```js
const banLinks = ["hello.com","test.net","this.com"];
// is_banned is now a function that ingests a link.
const is_banned = (myLink) => banLinks.findIndex(bl => myLink.indexOf(bl) > -1) > -1
// Get first link from titlesArray that is not banned.
const urllink = titlesArray.map(t => t.link).find(li => is_banned(li) == false)
```

Though this is all guessing based on the code you've provided. It's not very clear what you're attempting to do in your for loop. If it's to find the first valid (i.e., NOT banned) `urllink`, you should `break` after you've found it. Otherwise, subsequent valid `urllink`s from the rest of `titlesArray` will override the earlier ones.

Comment: thanks for your answer, no i don't need compatibility with IE. also with my for loop i was trying to say save the link inside urllink variable only if it (the link) doesn't contain any of the banned words present inside the array

Comment: @NathanBernard Then the code I provided should work. 

In my last line, `titlesArray` is scoured for any valid links. If one is found, then that is the value of `urllink`. If none are found, `urllink` will be `undefined`.

If you are attempting to 'find' something with a `for` loop, generally you'll want to `break` when you've found it.

Comment: Yes indeed things didn't make sense to me because i missed the break; that was the main culprit, now i could achieve it with loop and boolean basically, cause I figured out i also needed to check if all results were reached and accept a wrong url in case, just to avoid having an empty link. i'll mark this as the solution to my initial question anyway, it looks pretty simple too

Answer (score 0):

Say goodbye to indexOf() and use ES7 .includes() to check if an item is inside an array.

> I'd like to check if myLink I got through a.getAttribute("href")
> contains one of those words what'd be the best way to go?

```
if ( banLinks.includes(myLink) ){
                    urllink = myLink;
                }
```

Comment: I tried with includes but the result is the same, also wouldn't the logic be the opposite? to search the link for a word which is inside the array? or with includes is supposed to work both ways? i try again with the inverse logic as you wrote up here, but i think i already tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Please take a look

```js
const banLinks = ["hello.com","test.net","this.com"];
var bannedUrlTest = new URL("http://www.hellotest.net");
var safeUrlTest = new URL("http://www.google.net");

var safeUrl = null;
var bannedUrlArray = banLinks.filter((link)=>{
  return bannedUrlTest.href.includes(link)  
})

if(bannedUrlArray.length < 1){
  safeUrl = bannedUrlTest.href;
} else {
  console.log('contains banned links')
}

var safeUrlArray = banLinks.filter((link)=>{
  return safeUrlTest.href.includes(link)  
})

if(safeUrlArray.length < 1){
  safeUrl = safeUrlTest.href;
  console.log('safeUrl', safeUrl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="links">
      <li>
        <a href="hello.com">hello</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="steve.tech">steve</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="this.net">this</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Nathan.net">Nathan</a>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </body>
  <script>
      var links=[...document.querySelectorAll(".links a")]; //all links
      const BlackListLinks = ["hello.com","test.net","this.com"]; //BlackListLinks
      const goodLinks=[]; //stores the links don't in BlackListLinks
      for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {  //iterate over all links
        const link = links[i].getAttribute("href"); //get the current link
        if (!BlackListLinks.includes(link)){ //test if the current link don't exist in BlackListLinks
          goodLinks.push(link); //add link to the goodLinks 
        }
    }
      console.log(goodLinks);//["steve.tech", "this.net", "Nathan.net"]
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you search if the link is in the array or not, it's gonna fail if anything other than the proper array element string is there in the link like "www.hello.com"